# How can I prepare mysqli statement that uses arrays?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

Im using the below form

```
<form method="get" action="daily_process.php">
Horse / Course / Time 

<input type='text' name='horse[]' />
<input type="text" name="course[]" />
<input type="text" name="time[]" />

<input type='text' name='horse[]' />
<input type="text" name="course[]" />
<input type="text" name="time[]" />

<input type='text' name='horse[]' />
<input type="text" name="course[]" />
<input type="text" name="time[]" />


<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Im using the below code to process the form array and output it as print

```
<?php 
$horse = $_POST['horse'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
$time = $_POST['time'];

foreach( $horse as $key => $h ) {

if ($horse[$key] != "") {
  print "The horse is ".$h.", course is ".$course[$key].
        ", and time is ".$time[$key]." Thank you <br/>" ;
}}
?>
```

my question is how can I prepare these results for mysqli?

I have seen the below example on StackOverflow, but how can I edit it to suit my purpose?

ie. I need to save $horse, $course, and $timeto database - 
    table (horse,course, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (link) VALUES (?)"; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); 
foreach ($array as $one) { 
    $stmt ->bind_param("s", $one); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: If you have three parameters, why do you prepare and bind only one?

Comment: @Gumbo He's just showing an example that he copied from some other question, not his actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (horse,course,time) VALUES (?,?,?)"; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); 

foreach( $horse as $key => $h ) {
    $stmt ->bind_param("sss", $h, $course[$key], $time[$key]); 
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Assuming all the values are strings

The examples for bind_param in [the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) do show how to bind multiple values.